# how to use custom method for jQuery validation plugin and how to match string value

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jquery-validate

i am using jquery.validate.js for validation to identify duplicate entries

this is my custom method

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("uniqueName", function(name, element) {
    var response;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/getDuplicate",
        data:{"name":name},
        async:false,
        success:function(data){
            response = ( data == 'present' ) ? true : false;
        }
    })
     return response; 
}, "Name is Already Taken");
```

this is my Spring method in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/company/getDuplicate", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*/*")
    public @ResponseBody void getTitleList(@RequestParam(value="name") String name,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

       JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
       List<Company> matched = companyService.getDuplicate(name);

       System.out.println("Matched =====> "+matched);

       String s = "[]";

       if(s.equals(matched)){
           System.out.println(" Not Present");
           json.put("name", "notPresent");
           System.out.flush();
       }
       else{
           System.out.println("Present");
           json.put("name", "present");
           System.out.flush();
       }
   }
```

through this method i able to get data is duplicated or not (through 'matched' variable) , if data is present in database it return same data and if data is not present it return ' [] '
(because i used List type)

my problem is : in if statement condition is wrong, for all data it go to else block even if their is no data (i.e 'matched' variable return  ' [] ') . and how to set that status in custom validation method

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String s = "[]";    
 if(s.equals(matched))
```

This is not the way to check if a list is empty or not instead use `matched.isEmpty()` with a not null check .So your condition will be

```
   if(matched!=null && matched.isEmpty()){
       System.out.println(" Not Present");
       json.put("name", "notPresent");
       System.out.flush();
   }
   else{
       System.out.println("Present");
       json.put("name", "present");
       System.out.flush();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine please can you say how to use this in validation (please see above) at least give suggestion.

Comment: Vaildation? you mean in jquery.validation.js? Use data.name instead of just data.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your ajax method

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/getDuplicate",
            data:{"name":name},
            async:false,
            success:function(data){
                /* alert(data); */
                response = ( data == true ) ? true : false;
            }
        })
         return response;
    }, "Name is Already Taken");
```